# Highlight Menu Item When Viewing Single Post (not blog) with different category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

In order to highlight menu item when viewing single post (not blog), am trying to add special classes to single, (regular, not custom) posts from different categories. this is the basic code:

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
  if ( is_single() &&  (is_category('workshops') ) {
    $classes[] = 'special-class';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

its not working. the (is_category('workshops') piece is not quite right. works as expected when only

```
      if ( is_single() ) {
```

please correct! thank you!

Comment: How are you currently using PHP to echo your menu?

Comment: The menu is made using wp menus. The primary four items are pages. Tutorials is the only one with dropdowns—links that go to the specific filtered presentation on the Tutorials landing page. Current_page_parent is appended to Blog when showing any of the posts, otherwise the appropriate current page is highlighted. (I turned current_page highlighting off for posts for now).

Comment: i found a different solution. for posterity, the correction i was looking for is:

Comment: if ( is_single() && in_category ( '5' )  ) {

Comment: how i solved the problem was to add this code:  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/297278?replies=11#post-1396482   (or you could try using a plugin such as: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ambrosite-body-class-enhanced/). From there, you can style with css.